# How to pass dynamically an object to a modal

Tags: spring-boot, bootstrap-modal, thymeleaf

I'm trying to populate a modal dynamically.

First, I'm making a GET request via AJAX in which I send the desired object's id. Then I try update my model attributes so I can have the desired object. And this is where all fail. I can't update my model's attributes.

Otherwise everything works good. The modal opens but it doesn't have its html updated.

Ideally I would like this to be solved like:

1) Modal opens

2) Ajax request

3) Modal's html is updated

I'm using Thymyleaf as my template engine.

---

**MainController.java**

```
@RequestMapping("/main")
public String main(Model model)
{

    model.addAttribute("allVehicles", allVehicles);
    model.addAttribute("selectedCar", new Car());

    return "main";
}

@RequestMapping("/car/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public void car(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model)
{
    Car car = updateCarById(id);
    model.asMap().replace("selectedCar", car);
}
```

---

**main.html**

```
...
<div th:each="vehicle : ${allVehicles}">    
    <div th:each="car : ${vehicles.allCars}">
        <a th:onclick="'javascript:openModal(\'' + ${car.id} + '\');'">
        </a>
    </div>|
</div>
...
<script th:src="@{/js/car-viewer.js}"></script>
```

---

**car-viewer.js**

```
function openModal(id)
{
  $.ajax
  ({
      url: "/car/" + id,
      success: function (data) {
          $("#carViewModal").modal("show");
      }
  });
}
```

---

**carModalFragment.html**

```
<div th:fragment="carModalFragment">
<div class="modal fade" id="carModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="carModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="carModalLabel" th:text="${selectedCar.name}"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" th:text="${selectedCar.cost}"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pass complete object in function call instead of id only and update that object after ajax request is successful, it will update value in Html. i donno syntax of spring but it worked for me in angular.

Comment: Thymeleaf renders html on the server side. So, I can't update the model with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You have disconnects here between what you want, and what you have. For example:

In your modal you have many expression such as: `${selectedCar.name}`.  In your controller, you are setting `model.addAttribute("selectedCar", new Car());` which means that any expression where you use `${selectedCar}` will simply use a blank object.

In your ajax, you are calling this URL: `url: "/car/" + id,`.  Your controller for that URL isn't returning any data, it's simply returning a redirect `return "redirect:/main";` to another page.  (And the JavaScript is not doing anything with the return anyways, just displaying the modal.)

I think the easiest way to fix this would be:

In main controller, change it to return the car that is being selected:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/car/{id}")
public Car car(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model) {
    Car car = null;
    // car = findCarById(id); <-- implement this
    return car;
}
```

And second, change your ajax to set the attributes returned.

```
function openModal(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/car/" + id,
    success: function (data) {
      // Here, you should update the html with your selected car attributes
      $('#carModalLabel').text(data.name);
      $("#carViewModal").modal("show");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I want to pass the whole object. Not just the attributes. Essentially, the model needs to be updated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... the model is just the collection of all the attributes, right?  Can't you add all the attributes to the modal?

Comment: I mean the object's attributes. Not the model's attributes.
From your answer I understand that I must extract name, cost and other attributes from the object(car).
The problem is that the object is too complex to be implemented this way.

Comment: How else can you implement it? You want the html for your object automatically generated based on its attributes?

Comment: Yes, the HTML may vary and it's highly dependent on the object's attributes. Ideally I would like 1)modal opens, 2) screen display loading icon 3) ajax request 4) modal's html is updated

Comment: Well, there are far too many unknowns to take a stab at writing that.  If you have a question or problem w/examples etc..., that's one thing... but what you have here seems to me is basically writing the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

Try these adding to your controller.

```
@RequestMapping("/main")
public String main(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("allVehicles", allVehicles);
    model.addAttribute("selectedCar", new Car());
    return "main";
}

@RequestMapping("/car/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public String getCarView(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model)
{
    Car car = updateCarById(id);
    model.addAttribute("selectedCar", car);
    return "../pathToHtml/carModalFragment :: carModalFragment";
}
```

And changes your .js file below,

```
function openModal(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/car/" + id,
    success: function (response) {
      $("#carViewModal").empty().append(response);
      $("#carViewModal").modal("show");
    }
  });
}
```